# How to put a dollar symbol before every column and row number in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a big spreadsheet in google docs with many formulas like this: `=MIN(C3;C4)/500+4`. Now we need to add $ before every cell row/column to make it absolute. So, the formula should look like this: `=MIN($C$3;$C$4)/500+4`.

Is it possible to replace all these names in bulk, so I won't need to manually change each of them? Probably, a regexp could be used.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend upon what else you have in your spreadsheet. Text like "Minutes(Cardinal)" might require care. First I would have the formulae visible (View, All formulae or Ctrl+`).

Then it rather depends upon the formulae, of which you have only provided a single example. A column as the example that had been copied down could be changed with simple Edit, Find and Replace.... of `(C` with `($C` and `;C` with `;$C`, with *Also search within formulae*.

With two columns the same (say `C`s and also `D`s), Search using regular expressions could be applied to save repeating the above for `D`s, with finding:

```
(\()(.) and  
(\;)(.)
```

and in both cases replacing with:

```
$1$ $2
```

Two columns for example, but it could be the whole sheet. Unfortuantely that regex introduces spaces into the formulae, though those can then be removed quite easily and in bulk.

So possible, but a peculiar requirement for which they may be a better alternative solution.